# In bitRise facing issue of not loading input and out put file in iOS with Xcode version 14+

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode14, bitrise

❌  error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/razorpay-pod/razorpay-pod-xcframeworks-input-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'razorpay-pod' from project 'Pods')
❌  error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/razorpay-pod/razorpay-pod-xcframeworks-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'razorpay-pod' from project 'Pods')
❌  error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseAnalytics-xcframeworks-input-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'FirebaseAnalytics' from project 'Pods')
❌  error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseAnalytics-xcframeworks-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'FirebaseAnalytics' from project 'Pods')

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

`pod cache clean --all` This command is used to delete saved files on your computer that are used by CocoaPods. The command clears out all the saved files so that CocoaPods will need to download new files the next time it is used.

`arch -x86_64 pod install` This runs CocoaPods in a way that works on older Mac computers. If you have a newer Mac computer, this command can help make sure that everything is downloaded correctly, even if there are some compatibility issues.